# welcoming new members, member has no attribute 'server'

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am writing this bit that sends a message in a specific channel in a specific guild when a new member joins:

```
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    channel = get(member.server.channels, id=464298877823221763)
    await c.send(channel,"welcome")
```

I am getting weird errors when a new member joins:

```
Ignoring exception in on_member_join
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 312, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "d:/Documents/Bots/DS BOT/self_bot.py", line 53, in on_member_join
    channel = get(member.server.channels, id=464298877823221763)
AttributeError: 'Member' object has no attribute 'serve
```

Does anyone know how to solve this error?

Answer (score 2):

It's not server, but it's rather `guild`, you can try this code.

```
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    channel = bot.get_channel(channel-id)
    await channel.send(f"Welcome to {member.guild.name}!")
```

if you want to send where ever the member joins you can just do

```
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    await member.channel.send(f"Welcome to {member.guild.name}!")
```

Check out [guild documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=guild#discord.Guild) and the [member documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=member#discord.Member) or the [user documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=member#discord.User)

> Note. Sometime reading the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is helpful, don't forget that.

If you're using it on a cog, you'll need to do this.

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_member_join(self, member):
    channel = bot.get_channel(channel-id)
    await channel.send(f"Welcome to {member.guild.name}!")
```

> another note, i haven't touched commands.Cog.listener() in a while, so expect some errors

Answer (score 1):

In the API you should use `guild`, not `server`. A member can also be in many different guilds, so using `member.guild` will not work here. Try using [`client.get_channel(id)`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=client#discord.Client.get_channel).

```py
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    channel = bot.get_channel(464298877823221763)
    await channel.send("welcome")
```

Comment: I edited. I forgot to remove the `channel` argument from the `send` method. Sorry

Comment: NameError: name 'send' is not defined
I think it is useful to mention that I am using this event in a cog

Comment: Are you sure it is being caused by my code? Because the exception here would be `AttributeError: 'channel' has no attribute 'send'`.

Comment: I didn't see anything related to `send` in the image you posted. I highly doubt it is from mine because the error that should be happening here is `AttributeError`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214622/discussion-between-eric-jin-and-dan-a).